# Android List View , how to give a border and a background color to individual items in android list

Tags: android

I have created an android list and I want to give a border color to individual list items by checking a variable value and color the background according to the value. This is my work  so far .

The layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

       <ListView
          android:id="@+id/android:myalertlist"
          android:layout_width="250dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:clickable="true"
         android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

## My list view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtOne"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtTwo"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textIsSelectable="false" />



  </LinearLayout>
```

## @drawable/border_ui declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       android:shape="rectangle" >
```

-->

Activity Java Code

package test.application;

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    HashMap<String, String> hashMapOne = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMapOne.put("KEYONE", "EXPORT");
    hashMapOne.put("KEY_TWO", "A");

    HashMap<String, String> hashMapTwo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMapTwo.put("KEYONE", "IMPORT");
    hashMapTwo.put("KEY_TWO", "B");

    HashMap<String, String> hashMapThree = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMapThree.put("KEYONE", "IMPORT");
    hashMapThree.put("KEY_TWO", "C");


    HashMap<String, String> hashMapFour = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMapFour.put("KEYONE", "EXPORT");
    hashMapFour.put("KEY_TWO", "C");

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    hashList.add(hashMapOne);
    hashList.add(hashMapTwo);
    hashList.add(hashMapThree);
    hashList.add(hashMapFour);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, hashList,
            R.layout.list_test, new String[] { "KEYONE",
                    "KEY_TWO" }, new int[] { R.id.txtOne,
                    R.id.txtTwo });

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.android_myalertlist);
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

I still have a no clue to highlight and color the individual items. If anyone can guide me I would be thankful. [image]

Comment: you should use a custom listview with a custom adapter. then set the shape drawable as background to each element in listview

Comment: @Kalanamith i am sorry but can i ask you? why my answer did not help you?

Comment: this is the fact. Yesterday when I tried to accept your answer stackoverflow said it already deleted and now its there :) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own adepter class and a row layout. please look at this exaple.

and in the  getViev event you should change your background

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView label;
    protected Linearlayout layout;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_task_layout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.layout= (LineerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.label.setText(data.get(position).title);

        if(statement)
          {
             holder.layout.setBackground(background);
          }
        return view;
    }

}
```

rowlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F3F3F3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_main_single"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```